# Dojox/mvc/at model scope

Tags: model-view-controller, dojo

When using a Stateful object in the dojox/mvc package, the declarative examples seems to have the target model in the global namespace (defined without the "var" keyword). This violates the general practices of good Javascript design by polluting the global namespace, not to mention making the use of different models difficult and messy.

My question is, what's the scope of that declarative at() and how would one use a model that lies inside a certain context/scope?

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mvc.html#id6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where [dojox/mvc/at](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mvc/at.html) API is typically used in is [data-dojo-props](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/parser.html#parser-parameters). Three things comes to my mind talking about setting "scope" there:

1. Running [Dojo parser](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/parser.html) with `parser.parse(rootNode, {propsThis: scopeObj});` you can make `this` in [data-dojo-props](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/parser.html#parser-parameters) the specified object. In this way `data-dojo-props="widgetProp: at(this, 'scopeObjProp')"` points to a property in `scopeObj`.
2. In [widgets-in-template](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin.html), `data-dojo-props="widgetProp: at(this, 'widgetsInTemplateProp')"` points to a property in widgets-in-template instance.
3. [Relative data binding](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mvc/at.html#relative-data-binding) makes `target` property in a widget up in DOM referred via "rel:" special syntax. Setting an object to the `target` property there, like `registry.byId("scopeWidget").set("target", {First: "John", Last: "Doe"});` in below example, will populate the value in `<input>`:

   ```
   <script type="dojo/require">at: "dojox/mvc/at"</script>
   <div id="scopeWidget"
    data-dojo-type="dijit/_WidgetBase"
    data-dojo-props="target: {}">
       <div>
           First:
           <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
            data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'First')">
       </div>
       <div>
           Last:
           <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
            data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'Last')">
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

Hope this helps.

Best,
Akira